# has anyone successfully used openrave to to IK for robots containing closed loops?

Tags: ros, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a robot arm with a four bar linkage and am a little unclear on what is the best methodology to represent it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68968/has-anyone-successfully-used-openrave-to-to-ik-for-robots-containing-closed-loops?/) by [loughnane](https://answers.ros.org/users/4638/loughnane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We tried this some time ago, but ultimately ended up not being able to generate ikfast IK for our four bar linkage arm. We modeled the arm using mimic joints, but at least at the time we tried, generating IK for those was not possible using OpenRAVE. Not sure if this changed.

See this [Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/40932/urdf-using-mimic-joints-and-conversion-to-openrave-format/#40947).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2